# Scrolling Iframe page to the middle automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to scroll the content of the iframe to the middle of the page automatically. This is the script:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $redLink; ?>" width="300" height="155" frameborder="0">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it would be

```
var middle =  (($('iframe').height()) / 2);
$('iframe').scrollTop(middle);
```

Comment: `$('iframe').height()` returns the height of the iframe, not it's contents. So this won't scroll to the middle

Comment: Who, what, where? I cannot understand the question actually anymore! To `scroll the content of the iframe to the middle of the page automatically` the  `iFrame` has to be bigger than the page. jQuery is not asked here anyway. %)P However, this scrolls the page to the middle of the `iFrame`, assumed the `iFrame` is on the top of the page!

Comment: I think the question is asking that the iframe is scrolled to the middle of it's content - which isn't possible cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

I went to w3c.org using latest FF, Chrome and IE9 and threw the following into the JS console (it worked in all three).

```
var fr = document.createElement("iframe");
fr.src = "http://w3c.org";
fr.onload = function() {
    var de = (this.contentDocument||this.contentWindow.document).documentElement;
    var bd = de.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    de.scrollTop = bd.scrollTop = Math.floor(bd.scrollHeight / 2);
}
document.body.appendChild(fr);
```

**So all you need is to add the onload function to your markup**

```
onload="(function() {
    var de = (this.contentDocument||this.contentWindow.document).documentElement;
    var bd = de.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    de.scrollTop = bd.scrollTop = Math.floor(bd.scrollHeight / 2);
})()"
```

Comment: My console shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined` using this snippet

Comment: Also, `this` would refer to the global window variable, not the iframe.